# I need to upload a file and take the file name from the address

Tags: powershell-2.0

The code below will open an initial window where you need to input the number of files you are uploading, after that in the next window you select the files to be uploaded. Here you will see the full path of the file you have uploaded but I need only the file name that is selected, NOT the full path that is showing .e.g. `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: C:\Users\Gourav Bid\Desktop\pwd.txt`. I only need to take out the `pwd.txt`.

```psh
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

###### Initial Form Design ######

$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$objForm.Text = "File Upload"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,200)
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$objForm.KeyPreview = $True
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape")
{$objForm.Close()}})

###### Label & TextBox Design ######

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(40,20)
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$objLabel.Text = "Enter The Number Of Artefacts File Required :"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel)

$objTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$objTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(40,40)
$objTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$objForm.Controls.Add($objTextBox)

###### Operation Buttons & Cancel Button Design ######

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(40,80)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(70,20)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.Add_Click{(Button), $objForm.Close()}
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(120,80)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(70,20)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

function Button {
    [int]$artefacts = $objTextBox.Text
    $d = 100 + $artefacts*30
    $OKLoc = $d-70

    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

    $Form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $Form1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,$d)
    $Form1.Text = "Select Artefacts Files"
    $Form1.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
    $Form1.AutoScroll = $True
    $Form1.KeyPreview = $True

    ############################################## Buttons ##############################################
    $OKButton1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $OKButton1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,$OKLoc)
    $OKButton1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
    $OKButton1.Text = "OK"
    $OKButton1.Add_Click({$x=$objTextBox.Text;$Form1.Close();{split};Write-Host "$arte1"})
    $Form1.Controls.Add($OKButton1)

    $CancelButton1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $CancelButton1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,$OKLoc)
    $CancelButton1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
    $CancelButton1.Text = "Cancel"
    $CancelButton1.Add_Click({$Form1.Close()})
    $Form1.Controls.Add($CancelButton1)

    ############################################## Buttons ##############################################

    if ($artefacts -eq 1) {
        $Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
        $Label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,20)
        $Label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,20)
        $Label.Text = "File 1"
        $Form1.Controls.Add($Label)

        $arte = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
        $arte.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,15)
        $arte.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
        $Form1.Controls.Add($arte)
    }
    $Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(270,$OKLoc)
    $Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
    $Button.Text = "Browse"
    $Button.Add_Click({Button})
    #Write-Host $test
    $Form1.Controls.Add($Button)

    #####################################################Function Button#####################################################

    function Read-OpenFileDialog([string]$WindowTitle, [string]$InitialDirectory, [string]$Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*", [switch]$AllowMultiSelect) {
         Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
         $openFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
         $openFileDialog.Title = $WindowTitle
        if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($InitialDirectory)) {
          $openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = $InitialDirectory
        }
        $openFileDialog.Filter = $Filter

        if ($AllowMultiSelect) {
          $openFileDialog.MultiSelect = $true
        }

        $openFileDialog.ShowHelp = $true
        # Without this line the ShowDialog() function may hang depending on system configuration and running from console vs. ISE.

        $openFileDialog.ShowDialog() > $null
        if ($AllowMultiSelect) {
            return $openFileDialog.Filenames
        } else {
            return $openFileDialog.Filename
        }
    }

    function Button {
        for ($a=0;$a -lt $artefacts;$a++) {
            $b = $a+1
            $arte[$a].Text = Read-OpenFileDialog -WindowTitle "Select File $b" -InitialDirectory "C:\" -Filter "ALL files (*.*)|*.*"
        }
        Write-Host "$arte"
        $arte1=$arte
    }

    function Split {
        $arte1.split('\')[1]#.split(',')[0]
        Write-Host "$arte1"
    }

    #####################################################Function Button

    if ($artefacts -gt 1) {
        $b = 20
        $c = 15

        for ($a=0;$a -lt $artefacts;$a++) {
            $d = $a + 1

            $Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
            $Label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,$b)
            $Label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,20)
            $Label.Text = "File $d"
            $Form1.Controls.Add($Label)

            [Array]$arte += New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
            $arte[$a].Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,$c)
            $arte[$a].Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
            $Form1.Controls.Add($arte[$a])


            $b = $b+30
            $c = $c+30
        }
    }

    $Form1.Add_Shown({$Form1.Activate()})
    [void] $Form1.ShowDialog()
}

$objForm.Topmost = $false

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. Please post a [minimal, complete and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example which demonstrates the problem you're trying to solve - **not** your entire script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Split-Path` if you only need the file name:

```
Split-Path "C:\Users\Gourav Bid\Desktop\pwd.txt" -Leaf
```

outputs

```
pwd.txt
```

In your example, you can replace

```
Write-Host "$arte"
```

with

```
$arte | % { Write-Host (Split-Path $_.Text -Leaf) }
```

it will iterate on `$arte`, and extract the filename from the `.Text` property.

The output you get is the whole `TextBox` object, you need to specify which property you want, in this case `.Text`.

Comment: the output i am getting is "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: C:\Users\Gourav Bid\Desktop\pwd.txt" after running the script... can you suggest how can i use Split-Path  in this case or is there any mistake from my side for which i am getting "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text:" as unwanted part in the output

Comment: Thanks for the help... your suggestion was helpful for me :)

Comment: You're very welcome. You can accept the answer by clicking on the green check under its votes, if you will.